# Simple Question About Binomial Theorem

Tags: binomial-coefficients

On one of my calculus lectures I've seen the lecturer write:

$$(1+p)^n=1+np+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}p^2+\cdots+p^n$$

Could you please explain to me how did he get this equation?

Thank you very much.

Comment: As your title indicates, he used the [Binomial Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)  The link supplies a proof. It is the proof that you have difficulty with?

Comment: yes, I guesses he used the Binomial Theorem, but doesn't the Binomial Theorem looks a bit different than this?

Comment: If you expand the expressions on the Binomial theorem, you should get those numbers.

Comment: What does the binomial theorem look like if you spell out each coefficient instead of using fancy notation like $\binom{n}{i}$?

Comment: @Anonymous: Different?

Comment: In the Wikipedia version, put $x=1$ and $y=p$.

Comment: Sorry for the question, after applying it with x=1 and y=p I got the same equation. Sorry and thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can show the binomial theorem by induction starting from $(1+p)^0=1$ or $(1+p)^1=1+p$

For the abbreviated form you have, you can indicate $$(1+p)^n=(1+p)(1+p)^{n-1}$$ $$ 
=(1+p)\left(1+(n-1)p+\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}p^2+\cdots+p^{n-1}\right) $$  $$ 
=1 +p + (n-1)p+ (n-1)p^2+\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}p^2+\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}p^3+\cdots+p^{n-1}+p^n $$ $$= 1+np+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}p^2+\cdots+p^n$$

Answer (score 0):

One can also employ generating functions if you already know the power series for $\rm{\it e}^x$

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\rm {\it e}^{\:(a+b)\:x}\ &=&\rm\ {\it e}^{\:ax}\:{\it e}^{\:bx} \\
\rm \sum \frac{((a+b)\:x)^n}{n!}\ &=&\rm\ \sum \frac{(ax)^n}{n!}\ \sum \frac{(bx)^n}{n!} \\
\rm \frac{(a+b)^n}{n!}\ &=&\rm\ \sum \frac{a^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\frac{b^k}{k!} \quad  by\ comparing\ coef's\ of\ x^n\ above\\
\rm (a+b)^n\ &=&\rm\ \sum \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} a^{n-k} b^k\: =\: \sum {n\choose k} a^{n-k} b^k
\end{eqnarray}$$

The structure at the heart of the above has widespread applications. It is brought to the fore when one studies *Umbral Calculus*, e.g. see the book by that name by Steven Roman.